# FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION but there is no field with a filter

Tags: lookup-filter

Full message:

> FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION - Value does not exist or does not
>   match filter criteria.

Since a few weeks, I found out today, custom objects records cannot be created due to this error. I have two custom objects, Order and Invoice, related via Master-Detail to Account. Both have no filter on this relation and both do not have another field with a filter on it. I have checked and double checked.

Till a few weeks ago, everything worked OK, but suddenly no Invoice objects cannot be created anymore.

I created a sandbox and in this sandbox it is not possible to create either an Order or an Invoice object. In both cases I get the FIELD_FILTER error.

I looked in the Setup Audit Trail and some things happened around the time that this stopped working. Mainly the activation and deactivation of users, in particular the deactivation of the user who was the main contact of the org. But I cannot relate this to the problem I am experiencing. In fact, I have re-activated that user and it doesn't solve the problem.

I checked the unit tests on both production and the sandbox: they create Order and Invoice objects and they run without errors.

Comment: Please include the error message *verbatim*. That is only part of the error message, no?

Comment: Added the full message. The official help page of Salesforce says: in case of this message, check all fields of the object, to see if one of them has a filter.

Comment: Are there field filters on Account? Are there Roll-Up Summary Fields on the Account from the child objects?

Comment: Have you tried checking Related Lookup Filter for those objects. If their is a filter for lookup and that filter doesn't matches with the data you have given then you will be facing this error

Comment: @DavidReed Account has several roll-up summary fields for the child objects. But these exist already for a long time.

Comment: @EagerinSf I wrote in my question that I checked and double checked that the objects have no other related objects.

Comment: I think you are aware of this Related lookup Filter. If their is a lookup filter on any object you need to check that object. In this case you need to check all of your three objects.The Related Lookup Filter consists of Field Criteria, Error message as Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.I'm sure that this is causing you the above mentioned error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, using System.debug to see what the record looked like that was going to be inserted. The Name attribute had the value null. Well, that is never going to work. The fact that the unit tests worked indicated to me that filter criteria were not the problem. In this case it was the value of the key (Name).

The last update to the code that handles this is from October 2017, but the class gets the data from another system, so I have to look what is actually being received from that other system and if something changed to that a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: When the `Name` field is null it should just auto-populate with the `Id` instead. This find seems a bit suspect. I think you may have more digging to do.

Comment: No, I fill the Name field myself, the other system provides unique values (well, it should do that). My latest diggings seem to indicate that for some reason, all fields are now null.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Populating null as the Name should never cause an error.

Comment: Well, when I created the custom object, I chose to have Name as key, not Id. This gave me the responsibility to provide a unique value. And it has always worked, until a few weeks ago.